# Why did Feynman use a negative sign while defining the potential energy function?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy, conventions, conservative-field

Why is it ($-U$) and not ($+U$)?
And how do we know it's going to help us if we take it to be negative beforehand?

[image: Image from the Feynman lectures]

Comment: It is in general better to type out the question rather than just posting a screenshot. Regardless, some resources on the sign convention for potential energy are here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work+conventions+potential-energy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential energy function sign depends on exact potential form definition. Usual convention is to use such sign of potential energy, so that field accomplished work by moving a particle from *higher* potential energy area to *lower* potential energy area, should be **positive**. So for example gravitational potential energy near Earth surface is defined as :
$$ E = \pmb+mgh $$,

So that work done by gravity field is
$$ W = E_2 - E_1 = mg\,(h_2 - h_1) \gt 0 $$

Now if two masses are separated apart by huge distances, then gravitational potential takes universal form of :

$$ U = \pmb- \frac {\alpha}{r} $$

So, for example Earth done work by attracting moon closer from distance $r_2$ to $r_1$ is :

$$ W = U_2 - U_1 = \alpha \left(\frac 1r_1 - \frac 1r_2\right) \gt 0$$, again positive work done by gravity.

Answer (score 2):

The negative is just a convention that essentially makes the total mechanical energy $E=K+U$ rather than $E=K-U$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: But what problems would we face if it were K - U ? Just curious!

Comment: Probably knowledge of definite integral and boundary conditions will help in understanding the fact of Negative signs.